# regex - replace multi line breaks with single in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

this is some kind of variable content in javascript:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Some Meep meta, awesome</title>




    <-- some comment here -->
    <meta name="someMeta, yay" content="meep">

</head>
```

I want to reduce the multi line breaks (unknown number) to a single line break while the rest of the formatting is still maintained. This should be done in `javascript` with a `regex`.

I have problems with the tabulator or to keep the format.

Comment: Why? This won't update or change the source of the page, and I can't believe that white-space is an issue in the DOM (if it's preserved at all). I'm not saying you *shouldn't* do this, but I can't see why it benefits you. So there might be another approach to the problem, which is a better solution.

Comment: you can do it in vim with this regex `:g/^$/d`

Comment: @DavidThomas it is for a kind of a beautifer

Comment: So it's replacing/removing white-space in text presented on-screen? Not in the actual HTML source/DOM of the page itself?

Comment: "This should be done in javascript with a regex." --- sounds like a job description

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try this:

```
text.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n');
```

This basically looks for two line breaks with only whitespace in between. And then it replaces those by a single line break. Due to the global flag `g`, this is repeated for every possible match.

#### edit:

> is it possibile to leave a double line break instead of a single

Sure, simplest way would be to just look for three line breaks and replace them by two:

```
text.replace(/\n\s*\n\s*\n/g, '\n\n');
```

If you want to maintain the whitespace on one of the lines (for whatever reason), you could also do it like this:

```
text.replace(/(\n\s*?\n)\s*\n/, '$1');
```

Comment: is it possibile to leave a double line break instead of a single, that i have a distance between the lines ? :)

Comment: I tried your solution and it works but I don't understand why. 
I read that regex is matched "eagerly", meaning that it takes the first match it finds. Why doesn't this regex match every two adjacent newlines and replaces it with one newline then?

Comment: @AmerMograbi It does take two adjacent newlines and replace it by a single one. For example running this on `foo\n\nbar` will return `foo\nbar`. The eager matching usually refers to the fact that regular expressions will match *as much as they can get*, which is why this expression works to match multiple line breaks, e.g. `\n\n\n`. Otherwise, it would just match the first line break, then match nothing for the `\s*` and match the second line break, leaving the third one untouched.

Comment: @poke Oh, I get it now, thanks! It seems that I misunderstood what they meant by "eager".

Answer (score 19):

```
myText = myText.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');​​​​​​​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SsLb6/)

Answer (score 3):

Given the following (remember to encode HTML entities such as `<`, `>` and (among others, obviously) `&`):

```
<pre>
&lt;head&gt;

    &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;

    &lt;title&gt;Some Meep meta, awesome&lt;/title&gt;




    &lt;-- some comment here -->
    &lt;meta name="someMeta, yay" content="meep"&gt;

&lt;/head&gt;
</pre>
<pre>
</pre>​
```

The following JavaScript works:

```
var nHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].textContent.replace(/[\r\n]{2,}/g,'\r\n');
document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode(nHTML));​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Np3L/).

Answer (score 1):

To replace all the extra line breaks and leave only one use:

```
myText = myText.replace(/\n\n*/g,'\r\n');​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError