# Allow maximum single line gap instead multiline when using pre-line property in white-space

Tags: html, css

Although many question found with `white-space` keyword but none of the solving my issue that's why I posted this question.

I have a `p` container which containing long text from third party service. I formatted text with following CSS:

```
p { 
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

HTML structure like following:

```
<p> Test note for checking space issue please ignore this note.
Test note for checking space issue please ignore this note.



Test note for checking space issue please ignore this note.





Test note for checking space issue please ignore this note.</p>
```

So it is working as expected where single line gap showing single line and 
where multi line gap showing multi line. But I want to show only maximum single line gap instead where have multi line gap. For better understand see the illustration below.

[image]

Is it possible, anyone can help me figure out this issue?

Thanks in advance for your effort.

Comment: Right click on that paragraph tag, and check line-height

Comment: @MileMijatovic I checked and it is nor related to line-height because first two line showing properly.

Comment: Do you have some live example or jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue ?

Comment: There is no white space option to collapse multiple empty lines. W3school link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: @MileMijatovic he's using white-space: pre-line and thus the behavior .. have a try and you will see

Answer (score 1):

There is no value of `white-space` to remove multiple empty lines.

However according to this answer: [regex - replace multi line breaks with single in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965433/regex-replace-multi-line-breaks-with-single-in-javascript)

You can do with the help of Javascript/Jquery using Regex
`text.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n');`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t5bcw275/